# Meteor Setup Failure

Tags: meteor

There seems to be a problem with the Meteor Setup program on Windows 10. I get the following message.

"One or more issues caused the setup   to fail. Please fix the issues and the retry setup. For more  information see the log file"

"0x800706652 - Another installation is already in progress. Complete the installation before proceeding with this install".

The problem is that I'm getting this message even when I am no other Meteor setup process is running.I checked task manager and there is definitely nothing else from Meteor running. I restarted my PC to make sure, then ran setup before running anything else and I still got this message every time I run setup.

(Unfortunately, I can't post the  the contents of the setup log file, as it contains to many  links for thelevel of reputation points I have on stack overflow, as I am a new StackOverFlow user).

Please advise

Comment: could it be other installation services other than meteor such as windows update? have u tried this and end all the thing with "MSIExec.exe" ?https://support.threattracksecurity.com/support/solutions/articles/1000070783-msi-error-1618-another-installation-is-already-in-progress-during-installation-uninstallation

Comment: Yes it turned out to be exactly that and I was able to stop this via task manager. Thanks